# C++ How to selectively replace function with empty implementation

Tags: c++, templates, preprocessor-directive

I have a function that is littered throughout my code. It is used for development, but I don't want it to run in the final system. One way to do this is with macros:

```
#if SPEAK_ENABLED
   #define speak(m) implementation(m)
#else
   #define speak(m) ((void)0)
#endif
```

This works well, but I was wondering if there's any other mechanism (perhaps using templates) that I can use to get a similar behavior.

One thing I tried was declaring a function and then providing an implementation in all my main .cpp files. For example:

enable.h:

```
void speak()
{
        std::cout << "Output enabled" << std::endl;
}
```

disable.h:

```
void speak()
{
}
```

silent_main.h:

```
#include "disable.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        speak();
        return 0;
}
```

talking_main.h:

```
#include "enable.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        speak();
        return 0;
}
```

This works for simple cases like the above, but it won't work in my libraries because they will complain about lacking the definition of the function when they are being linked.

This is basically my use case. I want to disable this function for one executable target, but enable it for all others.

Is this just one of the instances where it is justifiable to use macros?

Comment: Your macro example is actually wrong - in the `#if` branch you shouldn't terminate the expanded command with a semicolon and in the `#else` branch you should expand to a no-op `((void)0)` instead

Comment: Thanks for the info. That makes sense. I quickly copied it from elsewhere. I will edit to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are still useful<sup>1</sup> for "conditional compilation" - at least given the advantage you can define or undefine them right in arguments of most compiler's invocation.

For example, this is useful in *`#include <cassert>`*'s [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), and its relationship with `NDEBUG` macro.

---

If `SPEAK_ENABLED` depends on some compile time property of a type or non-type, then you can use a templates, and how you are going to do it depends on your use-case.

<sup>1</sup>: However, if `SPEAK_ENABLED` depends on some environment property known before compiler's invocation, then MACROs may still hold some relevance.

---

> This works for simple cases like the above, but it won't work in my
>   libraries because they will complain about lacking the definition of
>   the function when they are being linked.

Provide an empty definition for the `speak()` for the "disabling case", a good optimizer will likely remove the call.

Comment: My problem with the templates is a dependency issue. For example, I can define a function that accepts int as a template parameter, but there's no way that I can define that int from my main.cpp files so that it gets picked up in my libraries. I guess in this case the only solution is macros.

Comment: Well, now it compiles with macros but I have a similar issue. The macro is not set in the dependent libraries, so they still do the full speak() function, while my main.cpp executable has it disabled. I may need to use some more complicated makefile stuff to really get it working in all my dependent libraries...